# can't push huge git commit

Tags: git, push, bitbucket

I have a huge 11Gb repo with Android sources.
I created repo with "git init", then one single commit with "git commit --all ."
I can't push it to remote repo, when I issue "`git push -u origin --all`"
It's stuck with executing 
`"git pack-objects --all-progress-implied --revs --stdout --thin --delta-base-offset --progress"` . Speed of reading data is just about 1Mb/s as iotop says. bitbucket refuses with message "fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly" and nothing is yet pushed as git does the job locally.
How to disable this packing and go further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git gc` helps.

```
/s/wand$ git gc
Counting objects: 346126, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (328144/328144), done.
Writing objects: 100% (346126/346126), done.
Total 346126 (delta 67519), reused 0 (delta 0)
Removing duplicate objects: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking connectivity: 346126, done.
/s/wand$ git push -u origin --all
Counting objects: 346126, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (260625/260625), done.
Writing objects: 100% (346126/346126), 3.11 GiB | 2.62 MiB/s, done. 
Total 346126 (delta 83231), reused 330414 (delta 67519)
To git@bitbucket.org:repu1sion/wand.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
```

Comment: I tried to move a large repository ~5GB to another git-host. For that I used Tortoise Git GUI for Windows which hang up every time I tried around 1GB.
Using git bash on the same system worked for me to push the repository.

Answer (score 3):

Your repository is [way too big for Bitbucket](https://blog.bitbucket.org/2014/05/30/repository-size-limits/):

> In order to improve and maintain the overall performance for everyone who uses Bitbucket, we are rolling out size limits on newly-created repositories. Starting [May 30, 2014], repository size limits will be:
>
> - **Soft limit** of 1 GB – In-product and email notifications will give you a heads-up that you’re approaching the limit.
> - **Hard limit** of 2 GB – Pushing to the repository will be disabled until you’re back under the limit.

Comment: And how could I reduce the size of repository after I pushed it already and it switched to read-only mode?

Comment: @pulse, what do you mean by "after I pushed it already and it switched to read-only mode"? Going from 11GB to 1GB is going to be difficult no matter how you slice it. Most Android-based projects are made up of several smaller Git repositories instead of one giant one. These are usually managed with a tool called [`repo`](https://code.google.com/p/git-repo/).

Comment: Chris, after git push finished its execution I got a message right in terminal that 2Gb limit overtaken and now repository is in read-only mode.
i tried to push an empty next commit - and it was forbidden. So the question is - how can I reduce the size of repository if the only option is "delete" ?

Comment: @pulse, I imagine you'd have to reduce the size of your repository (e.g. split it into multiple repositories as I already suggested, remove large files from history, etc.) and force push the new repository. There are implications to any of these options that should be well-understood. Since you're working on Android I do strongly suggest using `repo`, but you might still have problems with the size of your repositories.